# Why doesn't lodash deepClone make a deep clone of Function properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Using lodash deepClone works when the object has Array/Object or primitive properties.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const countries = [ 
  {
    name: 'United States of America',
    capital: 'Washington D.C.',
    languages: [ 'English' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'China',
    capital: 'Beijing',
    languages: [ 'Mandarin', 'Cantonese' ]
  },
];

const countriesClone = _.cloneDeep(countries);

console.log(countries[0] === countriesClone[0]); // returns false
```

But it doesn't seem to work on Function properties:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const sayHi = () => { console.log('hi')};
const sayBye = () => { console.log('bye')};

const myFunctions = {
  sayHi,
  sayBye
};

const myFunctionsClone = _.cloneDeep(myFunctions);

console.log(myFunctions.sayHi === myFunctionsClone.sayHi); // returns true
```

Is this the intention, and if so why?
I assumed that Array, Object and Function would all be treated equally, since they are all reference types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reliable way to clone a function in JavaScript, so that's why Lodash doesn't do so.

The [documentation for `_.clone`](https://lodash.com/docs/#clone) lists several types of values as uncloneable (and implies that there are others):

> An empty object is returned for uncloneable values such as error objects, functions, DOM nodes, and WeakMaps.